# Loopj's AsyncHttpclient not setting the correct timeout

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I tried setting my asynchttpclient's timeout in my singleton class but it seems that it doesn't change.
I got the 10000 which I think is the default value.

```
client.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(0,5000);
Log.i("loopj", ""+ client.getTimeout());
```

EDIT:

```
client.setTimeout(5000);
```

this method is working but for the information, how come setMaxRetriesAndTimeout doesn't?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I got it. From the [docs](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html#setMaxRetriesAndTimeout%28int,%20int%29),

setMaxRetriesAndTimeout - sets the maximum retries and timeout between those retries

setTimeout -  sets the connect/socket timeout - this one is the 10s by default