# Loopj AndroidAsyncHttp setTimeout

Tags: android, timeout, loopj, android-async-http

I'm using loopj 1.4.4 library to make HTTP request on my android device with 4.2.2.
setTimeout method is not working as expected:

```
public class RestClient {
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000;

    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public static void get(String url, RequestParams params,
            AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {

        client.setTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        client.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(1, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
        return Config.API_URL + relativeUrl;
    }
}
```

Using the code above I receive a timeout (specifically a onFailure callback) after
more or less 40 seconds...where am I wrong?
I think my code is not very different from this one: [Loopj's AsyncHttpclient not setting the correct timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853732/loopjs-asynchttpclient-not-setting-the-correct-timeout)

Comment: I guess setTimeout and setMaxRetriesAndTimeout set two different timeouts, of course you need to set it using setTimeout but 1 second I think is really low... did you try with 10 seconds (default value)? Same behavior?

Comment: Seems like the value I set is not considered. Always 40 seconds to failure.

Comment: Did you check all the onFailure methods? Could you please also post a logcat where you print a message when you make the request and then a message for each of the success/failure methods? Thanks a lot.

Comment: same exact problem.  Any solution?

Comment: I just ended using the default 10000 value and removing setMaxRetriesAndTimeout...also be sure to override the onFailure(Throwable e, String response) method of the library.